# need to write a sum(grades) / sum(credits) code

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sum

I am making a student database which contain the course id, course name, credits of each course, pass fail statement and the grades. 
my aim is to let the button show sum(grades) / sum(credits)

this is the code i wrode and it's giving me an error saying that "***there is already an opened datareader associated with this connection which must be closed first***."
there is my code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           string ConString = " datasource = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = 3306";
           string Query = " Select sum(grade) from studentdata.semestre1";
           string Query1 = " Select sum(grade) from studentdata.semestre1";
           MySqlConnection ConDatabase = new MySqlConnection(ConString);
           MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, ConDatabase);
           MySqlCommand cmdDataBase1 = new MySqlCommand(Query1, ConDatabase);

           MySqlDataReader myReader;
           MySqlDataReader myReader1;

            ConDatabase.Open();

            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader() ;
            myReader1 = cmdDataBase1.ExecuteReader();

            while ((myReader.Read()) && (myReader1.Read()))
            {
                textBox2.Text =Convert.ToString(double.Parse( myReader.GetString(0))/ double.Parse(myReader1.GetString(0))) ;
            }
            myReader.Close();
            myReader1.Close();
```

anyone can help ?

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it will be for users to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that that the datareader is in open state else where. It is simlar to connection object.You Don't have to create two times, you can do the same in a single query

```
  string ConString = " datasource = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = 3306";
  string Query = "Select SUM(grade)/SUM(credits) FROM studentdata.semestre1";
  MySqlConnection ConDatabase = new MySqlConnection(ConString);
  MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, ConDatabase);
  MySqlDataReader myReader;
  ConDatabase.Open();

  while ((myReader.Read()) && (myReader1.Read()))
        {
            textBox2.Text =Convert.ToString(double.Parse( myReader.GetString(0))) ;
        }
  myReader.Close();
```

Comment: thank youuu that worked perfectly :) 
plz i have another question : i want to save the average that i have in a different database that i have already created on mysql named semestre_ average ( it has 2 columns : 1 - semestre and 2 - average grade). how can i do it ?

Comment: The query in this answer is just a start.  You have to add something to prevent an attempt to divide by zero.  As far as copying the data elsewhere, that might be a waste of time and effort.  Why not simply use the data you have?

Comment: @DanBracuk i need to open a new form listing each semester and the average of each semester so i could calculate the cumulative average of all semesters. this is why i want to save the average data elsewhere. if you have another idea to accomplish what i need plz share it

Comment: Calculate it every time you need it.  By the way, doing calculations on averages is rarely a goo idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the first `MySqlDataReader` to open another one using the same connection. I advise you to use `using` keyword since `MySqlDataReader` implements `IDisposable`.

```
       double grades, credits;

       string ConString = " datasource = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = 3306";
       string Query = " Select sum(grade) from studentdata.semestre1";
       string Query1 = " Select sum(credit) from studentdata.semestre1";
       MySqlConnection ConDatabase = new MySqlConnection(ConString);

       ConDatabase.Open();
       using(MySqlDataReader myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader())
       {
          grades = double.Parse(myReader.GetString(0));
       }

       using(MySqlDataReader myReader1= cmdDataBase1.ExecuteReader())
       {
            credits = double.Parse(myReader1.GetString(0))) ;
       }

       ConDatabase.Close();

       textBox2.Text =Convert.ToString(grades/credits).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add  MultipleActiveResultSets=True to your connection string in order to open multiple datarteaders on the same connection.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx